# etc/update-motd.d added script which executes. But after change the old version is being executed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login, login-screen, login-script

My script executes OK. But when I altered it on next ligins the old one is still executing instead of the amended one. Do I need to refresh/restart something (except the system :) ) for my changes to be effective? (I ssh connect)